# Windows 11 installed on a refurbished HP so that I can't suppress Secure boot mode to boot on USB

Tags: boot, usb, multi-boot, windows-11, secure-boot

I recently bought a refurbished HP Z4 G4 with windows 11 already installed. In order to dual boot, I have to change the bios/UEFI Secure Boot to disable (and legacy to enable). I am able to change it with F10 (and bios password enabled) or by PowerShell with "BiosConfigUtility64.exe /set:Bootdisable.txt /nspwdfile:"mypasswd.bin" but each time the saved config disappears and while rebooting either with ESC or F9, on either a DVD or a USB stick, I get the message "selected boot image did not authenticate". And this message appears, according to Microsoft, to the fact that the Secure Boot is still on (which can be verified by msinfo32 or Confirm-SecureBootUEFI). Also while on Windows, the "shutdown /r /fw" does not reboot on UEFI settings as it should, but on Windows 11 again. I already spent a lot of time googling on this subject in vain.
(1) Does anyone have an idea on what to change on Windows 11 to be able to suppress this Secure mode?
(2) The C: partition is (and was) formatted with GPT. How can I reinstall Windows 11 in order to no more have this Secure mode enabled? I do not have the Serial number of this Windows 11 but I am able to produce a USB stick with Windows 11, version 22H2. Also I verified that I am able to boot on this special USB stick because the iso is certified by Microsoft. This is the only USB stick that I have been able to boot on.

Comment: Windows does not support Legacy Mode. Why exactly do you need to disable Secure Boot? Windows 11 can run without Secure Boot but it does it support Legacy Mode. FYI: There is absolutely nothing special about the flash media you have. It identical to one you can create with the Media Creation Tool

Comment: Why don't you use a Linux distribution that supports Secure Boot? Note that dual boot requires to disable Fast Startup in Windows.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not particularly interested in Legacy Mode but in being able to install a Linux distribution in dual boot and if I was able to reinstall Windows 11 without a secure boot (but I don't know if the windows 11 USB stick that I created, will be able to reinstall windows 11 with no secure boot, or if it will be reinstalled with the default secure boot (which can't be currently disabled). Also, Ubuntu for example or Fedora USB iso distributions are supposed to be Secure boot. But they are not bootable on this current installation. Fast Startup was disabled, for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 11 normally requires Secure Boot and UEFI to run.

If your other OS will not run with Secure Boot (I have one of those), then you must run it within a Virtual Machine.

It is truly best to run Windows 11 properly, Then, use a good VM App on your Windows 11 Host.  I use VMware Workstation and that works well.

Comment: It then means that dual boot can no more exist on a PC with Windows 11 (with Secure Boot enable). I already have some Windows VM on my MacBook pro and Virtual Box to test a scientific program on different Windows versions but it is not identical to having a native Linux box. I am a little lost in how to use shim.efi .

Comment: I suggest you just use a Virtual Machine and then you do not have worry about UEFI

Comment: Hi, I asked Rod Smith who wrote the webpage (http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/). Here is what he said _It's possible that your computer is defective and firmware settings changes are not "taking." If so, I'd recommend returning the computer for a replacement; even if you found a workaround, the inability to save settings to NVRAM will likely cause problems in the future._ He also added: _Before returning the computer, though, you might look for an option to reset all firmware options to their defaults. That sometimes fixes glitches and firmware malfunctions._

Comment: It is possible you have a hardware issue with the refurbished machine. But given your original post, you still likely will not succeed with dual boot requiring settings Windows 11 will not work properly with.

Answer (score 0):

A year after buying this desktop, I never solved the Windows 11 issue but I can certify (in contradiction with Rod Smith) that the hardware is not defective. My aim was to be able to dual boot Windows 11 and Linux. And as most of the Linux distributions do not propose the recent (Microsoft) secure boot, I changed from my older distribution Mageia to Fedora.

And I have been really surprised by the ease of install and use of Fedora, even with the secure boot. I know that I could use a Linux VM (which I have at work) but may be next time. Therefore Windows 11 and Fedora Linux are working successfully as dual boot with uefi. I hope that other Linux distros will enable secure boot too.